# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars --> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dtype

I wrote a VGG19 model to predict an array of features ( `x_train` ).

But, when I try to actually predict it using

`feature_extractor = model_vgg.predict(x_train)`,

I get the following error :

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).

So, I researched and found out that I need to use it as an integer or another Data Type because it will not directly convert.

To battle that, I did this :

`x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype("uint8")`

But lo and behold, I got an error.

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I researched about this error as well and tried different variations of the same code but it doesn't work.

Can someone please guide me on this ?

Comment: I suspect `x_train` to be ill-formed (ragged array, array of different types, etc..) and has as a  `dtype`: `object`. Try to get your feature matrix right, as an array of float or int with a the intended shape, and `dtype` different from `object` before casting it to `np.uint8`

Comment: @H.Rev. That definitely seems like what happened. How can I do that ?

Comment: Most likely your `x_train` was created from arrays or images that differ in shape.  You have the data, and only you can examine it and make sure it is consistent.  There isn't a superficial coding fix.